# What increases Android App size

Tags: android, cordova

i have made android app that is of just 20 mb , But when i goto manage apps and see size it show 70 mb there , i could not get why it is no , also my has no external data ,

My app is built using crosswalk+ codova hybrid app.

But i could not figure what case size to be almost more than triple.

Please guide

Does app size depend on

1: permission we gave : means more permission , more will be app size

Please help me to fix this issue as user might delete such large apps

Comment: Crosswalk would be about ~45mb of that

Comment: but my apk with inapp crosswalk is 21 mb

Comment: You may be able to use proguard to remove parts you don't need posibly.

Comment: APKs are compressed, when the app is installed the APK is uncompressed, so the real size is bigger

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are using Crosswalk Cordova it's like any other cross-platform that includes it's runtime within the project for every available architecture available (ARM, ARMV7, X86, MIPS) and that's too much as it would take much of space for an empty project with only one view around 20MB.

### What it will be the case if we use the native java android SDK?

The size will be much less than the same app done with a cross-platform environment because the android runtime is included in the system itself, you don't need to embed it into the application like you don on cross platform projects.

### Why did the size increase on the device?

Only because the APK file is a zipped file and it will be decompressed on the device to a bigger size. Try to unzip it on your computer and check the original size before compressing.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html

> How big is the Crosswalk Project runtime, and how will it affect my
>   application's size?
>
> Once this application is packaged with its own Crosswalk 10 (x86
>   Android) runtime, the apk file size is ~20Mb. Installed, the
>   application takes ~58Mb of disk space.

If you can survive without crosswalk then just package with the normal WebView and you'd save 60MB